# How do I use namespace package in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I know that a folder structure that I have is compliant with Python 3 and 2. Without using an `__init__.py` I would like to access the subfolders packges and `import` them

This is the folder structure

```
dir_1
   dir_2
      x.py
dir_3
   dir_2
      y.py
```

and I'm trying to do

```
from dir_1.dir_2.x import func_Z
from dir_3.dir_2.y import func_Z2
```

assuming those are the functions inside the files `x.py` and `y.py`

I have tried appending the super directory to `sys.path` but that doesn't help because Python2.7 doesn't import those modules.

I tried hacky versions of hand rolling the import but they do not import it to the correct namespace

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_dir):
     path = root.split(os.sep)
     for file in files:
         if file.endswith(".py"):
           sys.path.append(root)
           sys.modules[root.replace("/", ".")] = root.split(os.sep)[-1]
```

Comment: What's the name of class inside x and y?

Comment: call it class Z. I can edit it to import the class to make it more clear

Comment: In Python2, [namespace packages do *not* work without ``__init__.py``](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#creating-a-namespace-package). Why do you try to misuse ``sys.path`` instead of creating a proper Py2 namespace package?

Comment: So I am aware of the limitation. This is an codebase that unfortunately I cannot change. It will also soon be moving to Py3 where this is a moot point. In the meantime to get people over the hump, I wanted a temporary solution to allow the older Python 2 code to access some of the Python3 code